# Looking for a web server that include the following technologies ColdFusion, PHP, MS SQL Server, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, coldfusion, mssqlft

Can anyone explain if it is possible to have a web server for all of these technologies:

ColdFusion, PHP, MS SQL Server, MySQL

I have a web developer insisting that they require all of the above however it doesn't quite make sense to me.

Any help or clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, do you really need 2 databases?

Comment: BTW, this is a question for ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but MS SQL being a Windows only product, you'll need a Windows server, preferably one from the Server family (Windows Server 2003 or 2008). PHP and mySQL can run happily on Windows, I've got them both running on the Windows 7 machine I'm writing this on.

I don't know whether a hosting provider will run all these things on the same server in a standard (cheap) package - you may have to have one tailor-made. But that depends entirely on your situation, of course.

As to whether this makes *sense*, though - I don't know. Is this a new product being developed? Then it sounds very strange to need two different database platforms, and two entirely different web development environments. If it's to integrate a number of existing products, it may make sense.

Comment: Nah, with some work you can get CF to run on Linux. It's just not as straightforward.

Comment: @Kevin ah ok, wasn't sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is possible to have all of those technologies installed on a Windows server
2. It is possible to make a connection to both MS SQL and MySQL via both PHP and ColdFusion.
3. Providers usually have PHP and MySQL as combination, but the bigger providers have also windows based hosting with an MS SQL database server, so a connection from the PHP linux server can be made to a MS SQL server (you do need some special library installed though [I read](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6636)).
4. Not many providers offer ColdFusion hosting, at least not in a shared manner. There are a few, godaddy to say one among others such as hosting.com, take a google around the world to find them.
5. If you want to do this yourself, you could get a Windows VPS and install all the required software.
6. ColdFusion exists now also opensource, something not many seem to  know: Railo

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have all of those installed. We have a LAMP server that runs all of that but MSSQL. You could have a Windows box run all of them too. Not sure about MSSQL on Linux, but I know its definitely possible to have all that on a Windows box.